# Have child not cause parent to stay alive

Tags: node.js

The situation I have is a child process (created through fork), which listens to "message". The parent *does not listen to the child*. So basically the child is around to help if necessary. I'd like the parent to just die, instead it stays alive due to the on("message") in the child.

Parent:

require("child_process").fork("./child");

Child:

process.on("message"), function() { });